# Play runtime DI disadvantages

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework

I couldn't find much information about Play's runtime dependency injection versus compile time dependency injection in Scala. Compile time DI looks more appealing, but Play seems to encourage the opposite. Plus, the amount of boilerplate code required combined with the lack of documentation is discouraging.

My question is, what exactly are the disadvantages of using runtime DI in Play? Aren't all the components wired immediately when the application loads, which makes failures quick to detect?

Comment: The two sections on the website are fairly detailed - https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection and https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection

Answer (score 1):

The main difference in my mind is that failures in wiring are uncovered at runtime versus compile-time in the respective solutions. So if you forget to bind some interface to an implementation using runtime DI you will find out (potentially) when you deploy you're application. You're saved this potential headache with compile-time DI, at the cost of verbosity.

I would recommend to take a look at [macwire](https://github.com/adamw/macwire) which is a nice macro-based project for compile-time DI which alleviates some of the issues to do with boilerplate.

There's a sample play project with macwire on [github](https://github.com/playframework/play-macwire-di).

Comment: Is run time when play starts or can it be later, only when the  component is requested?

Comment: if you use lazy initialisation, it can be when the component is requested @nmat